# PySpark - Split all dataframe column strings to array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In PySpark, how to split strings in all columns to a list of string?

```
a = [('a|q|e','d|r|y'),('j|l|f','m|g|j')]
df = sc.createDataFrame(a,['col1','col2'])

+-----+-----+
| col1| col2|
+-----+-----+
|a|q|e|d|r|y|
|j|l|f|m|g|j|
+-----+-----+
```

Output expected:

```
+---------+---------+
|     col1|     col2|
+---------+---------+
|[a, q, e]|[d, r, y]|
|[j, l, f]|[m, g, j]|
+---------+---------+
```

I can do single column at a time by using `withColumn` but not an appealing solution with dynamic number of columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split    
outDF = df.withColumn("col1", split(col("col1"), "\\|").alias("col1"))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to create a list of column expressions first, and then leverage `select` method with *varargs* syntax:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split 
cols = ['col1', 'col2']                                               # columns to split
col_exprs = [split(col(x), "\\|").alias(x) for x in cols]
df.select(*col_exprs).show()
+---------+---------+
|     col1|     col2|
+---------+---------+
|[a, q, e]|[d, r, y]|
|[j, l, f]|[m, g, j]|
+---------+---------+
```

---

Another option using `reduce` from `functools` with `withColumn` to dynamically create new columns:

```py
from functools import reduce
reduce(
    lambda df, colname: df.withColumn(colname, split(col(colname), "\\|").alias(colname)), 
    cols, 
    df
).show()
+---------+---------+
|     col1|     col2|
+---------+---------+
|[a, q, e]|[d, r, y]|
|[j, l, f]|[m, g, j]|
+---------+---------+

reduce(lambda df, colname: df.withColumn(colname, split(col(colname), "\\|").alias(colname)), cols, df).explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# *Project [split(col1#0, \|) AS col1#76, split(col2#1, \|) AS col2#81]
# +- Scan ExistingRDD[col1#0,col2#1]
```

Comment: Can someone explain why the double backslashes in the split function? Thanks!

Comment: it is java regex, \\ is escape pattern, \ is in python @Luke